# what is exact difference between Spark Transform in DStream and map.?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to understand transform on Spark DStream in Spark Streaming.

I knew that transform in much superlative compared to map, but
Can some one give me some real time example or clear example that can differentiate transform and map.?

Comment: https://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/What's_the_difference_between_map_and_transform_in_spark_streaming

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `transform` function in Spark streaming allows one to use any of Apache Spark's transformations on the underlying `RDDs` for the stream. `map` is used for an element to element transform, and could be implemented using `transform`. Essentially, `map` works on the elements of the `DStream` and `transform` allows you to work with the `RDDs` of the DStream. You may find http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

`map` is an elementary transformation and `transform` is an RDD transformation

### map

---

> map(func) : Return a new DStream by passing each element of the source
>   DStream through a function func.

Here is an example which demonstrates both map operation and transform operation on a DStream

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("StreamingTransformExample")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))    

val rdd1 = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(1,2,3))
val rdd2 = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(4,5,6))
val rddQueue = new Queue[RDD[Int]]
rddQueue.enqueue(rdd1)
rddQueue.enqueue(rdd2)

val numsDStream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue, true)
val plusOneDStream = numsDStream.map(x => x+1)
plusOneDStream.print()
```

the `map` operation adds 1 to each element in all the RDDs within DStream, gives an output as shown below

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501135220000 ms
-------------------------------------------
2
3
4

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501135225000 ms
-------------------------------------------
5
6
7

-------------------------------------------
```

### **transform**

---

> transform(func) : Return a new DStream by applying a RDD-to-RDD function
>   to every RDD of the source DStream. This can be used to do arbitrary
>   RDD operations on the DStream.

```
val commonRdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(0))
val combinedDStream = numsDStream.transform(rdd=>(rdd.union(commonRdd)))
combinedDStream.print()
```

transform allows to perform RDD operation such as join, union etc upon the RDDs within DStream, the example code given here will produce an output as below

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501135490000 ms
-------------------------------------------
1
2
3
0

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501135495000 ms
-------------------------------------------
4
5
6
0

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501135500000 ms
-------------------------------------------
0

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501135505000 ms
-------------------------------------------
0
-------------------------------------------
```

here the `commonRdd` which contains the element `0` is performed a union operation with all the underlying RDDs within the DStream.

Answer (score 1):

DStream has Several RDD's, since every batch interval is a different RDD.
So by using transform(), you get the chance to to apply an RDD operation on the 
entire DStream.

Example from Spark Docs:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transform-operation

Answer (score 1):

The transform function in Spark Streaming allows you to perform any transformation on underlying RDD's in Stream. For example you can join two RDD's in streaming using Transform wherein one RDD would be some RDD made from textfile or parallelized collection and other RDD is coming from Stream of textfile/socket etc.

Map works on each element of RDD in a particular batch and results in the RDD after applying the function passed to Map.

Answer (score 0):

example 1)

men in a queuing coming inside a room,  changing the dress , then marry women of their choice.

1) Changing the dress is the map operation (  where they are transform themself in attributes )

2) Marrying woman is merge/filter operation on you but under impact of others  which we can call real transform operation.

example 2)
Student enters in college , few attended 2 lectures, few other attended 4, So on.

1) Attending lectures is map operation  , what typically students are doing.

2) but to identify what lecturer taught them depends on lecturer RDD data , his day agenda.

Assume Transform operation a Dimension or static table that you want to filter or verify to identify right data for you , and removing may be junk.

Answer (score 0):

If I am having data from 0-1 s "Hello How" and for the next 1-2 s " Are You" . Then in case of map and reduce by key example as shown above will produce the output (hello,1) and (How,1) for the first batch and (are,1) and (you,1) for the next batch.But similarly for the next example using "transform function" what will be the difference in the output