# What's the difference between foreachRDD and transform in spark streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

To use RDD operations we can use either `foreachRDD()` or `transorm()` but I can not understand what's the difference between them.

Comment: Not really a logical question imo. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168039/what-is-exact-difference-between-spark-transform-in-dstream-and-map.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421619/whats-the-meaning-of-dstream-foreachrdd-function